# HTML validation isn't validating?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, xhtml

I'm trying to validate my XHTML 1.0 but I've got 2 error's which I can't seem to fix no matter what. Could someone just take a look at it and if so provide alternatives to it? When I change 'email' to text my JS stops working.

```
Line 49, Column 58: there is no attribute "required"

…id="first-name"  type="text" required="required" onkeypress="return onlyAlphab…


Error Line 63, Column 41: value of attribute "type" cannot be "email"; must be one of "text", "password", "checkbox", "radio", "submit", "reset", "file", "hidden", "image", "button"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"required"` attribute and the `"type=email"` come with **HTML5**, **your document use xhtml 1.0 strict**.

You can :

- change the doctype to HTML5 : `<!DOCTYPE html>`

or

- remove those attribute / type :)

Comment: Is there any alternatives to it besides rewriting everything?

Comment: I just edited my answer : change your doctype or remove those part of code.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with XHTML not with HTML5 :/ So there's no alternatives? Just have to re-write my JS?

Comment: I'm afraid there's no alternative : you wanna use HTML5 element in non-HTML5 document. The real question is : why you wanna make it work as XHTML 1 strict if you use HTML5 ? :)

Comment: Post your JS part if you want some help with that.

Comment: It's just a requirement that I want for my website to validate in XHTML1.0, but looks like that isn't happening :(

Comment: Cheers for that, I've added my JS

Comment: Thank you. What is this JS supposed to do on the email input ? Checking email ? If so, it's because type="email" process email validation by default (HTML5 feature). So you have to check this entirely with JS from now. This topic can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript

Comment: What should my type be? text or still email?

Answer (score 0):

XHTML has no `input` of type `email` and has no form validation so `required` does not exists. Those are elements are added in HTML5